# Webkit JavaScript Reference

Tags: javascript, webkit

For Gecko there's Mozilla Developer Network

For IE there's MSDN.

For webkit there's...Apple Developer Connection?

There are a [couple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html) of JavaScript related documents on ADC, but nothing as comprehensive as MDN or MSDN. There's no reference. There's no way to look up methods of arrays or strings for webkit, or anything is there? So what, do we just assume it's the same as Gecko? IE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about the WebKit DOM Reference?

http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/index.html

**Update**

Thanks for the comments - yes this now redirects.

Perhaps as others have said, one of the other browsers' references would be a good place to start - then for Safari's own DOM extensions/additions, there's the 'Safari DOM Additions Reference':

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs

Otherwise it looks like it would be a case of finding your way through the confusing set of documents there in the Safari Developer Library:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/

Comment: That's new. Some more text here.

Comment: New but on first look seems not terribly useful. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't come close to MDC at all.

Comment: Now it redirects to the index of the Safari Developer Library.

Comment: Where is their original webkit reference site? Apple's hyperlinks ain't cool!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariJSRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001482 may work

Answer (score 6):

I use [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/) for all my JavaScript needs.  MDC is my resource for references and basic how-tos and quirksmode to show me that I, in fact, cannot even use it in IE.  WebKit and Gecko seem to behave similarly enough when it comes to JavaScript anyway.

But other than what you listed, I have never come across anything specific to WebKit.

Comment: `window.getSelection().setBaseAndExtent()` seems to be webkit only and I am having problems finding documentation :\

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of a WebKit JavaScript reference like MDN or MSDN. When I need to look something up, I use the Mozilla Developer Network, as Gecko and WebKit seem to be heading in roughly the same direction.

Steve

Comment: There is a reference of sorts - see poshaughnessy's answer.

Comment: On MDN site, for a given js feature, if you go down to browser compatibility you also see Safari (yes/no).