# Documentation for webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have been searching Google for that last 15 minutes trying to find Documentation on "webkit".  What I'm looking for is official documentation on file.webkitSlice.

I was using file.slice on Chrome, but I guess an update *nixed that.  I'm just trying to update some code.

I found webkit.org, but the main documentation refers to the actual build of webkit.

Comment: Have you read this bug report? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the closest we are getting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob

according to [Webkit JavaScript Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871460/webkit-javascript-reference)

Comment: Link to the official Webkit DOM docs related to Blob: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/Blob_idl/Classes/Blob/index.html