# Get Default Value From select field Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, default, default-value

I have a select field that have have present options and I have a php script check a mysql database and add a select tag to the one currently being used.

I need to find a way to know if the user have changed the select field or not before submitting it.

```
var Access = document.forms[UIDF]["Access"].value;
var DAccess = document.forms[UIDF]["Access"].defaultIndex; <--- This is my problem. I just need to know how to get the selected option value as this keep changing with every user

<select name="Access">
  <option value="0" selected='selected'>Employee</option>
  <option value="1">Team Leader</option>
  <option value="2">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Option` tag has a javascript attribute `defaultSelected` that's set to `true` if the option had a `selected` value on page load. Note that this is the `option` tag and not the `select` one, so you'll have to loop through the options and check for the attribute.

Something like

```
var DAccess;
var AccessSelect = document.forms[UIDF]["Access"];

for (var i = 0 ; i<AccessSelect.length ; i++)
{
    if (AccessSelect[i].defaultSelected)
        DAccess = AccessSelect[i].value;
}
```

Or, more to the point:

```
var AccessHasChanged = false;
var AccessSelect = document.forms[UIDF]["Access"];

for (var i = 0 ; i<AccessSelect.length ; i++)
{
    if (AccessSelect[i].defaultSelected && 
        AccessSelect.value != AccessSelect[i].value)
        AccessHasChanged = true;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation of javascript really, but here's a similar question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871460/webkit-javascript-reference