# What is the equivalent to 'defaultValue' for a <select> Menu?

Tags: javascript, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Default Value From select field Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215586/get-default-value-from-select-field-javascript)

I use a javascript function and the 'window.beforeunload' property to check to see if the user has made any changes to my web form before leaving the page. In this function I compare the defaultValue of the text fields with the value. However I have added two ListBoxes to the form and the defaultValue method isn't working for them. What can I use in its place for the Selects?

Text field example:

```
if(document.forms['form2']['itemID'].value != document.forms['form2']['itemID'].defaultValue)
{return 'There are unsaved changes in the form!'}
```

Comment: USE defaultSelected for Select box.... See this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_defaultselected.asp

Comment: @Pandian: [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com). Bad site is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `defaultSelected` for select's option elements.

REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionElement